# Smoother type annotation in bind chain

Tags: haskell

So I have this working example (Snap + Postgres):

```
listBooks :: AppHandler ()
listBooks = do
  results <- query_ "select * from books"
  writeJSON $ (results :: [Book])
```

As an exercise I'm trying to rewrite this with `>>=` operator, but the need to annotate type kills the aesthetics. I couldn't come up with anything better than:

```
query_ "select * from books" >>= return.(\x -> x :: [Book]) >>= writeJSON
```

Is there any other "smoother" way? (preferably without specifying the wrapping monad type)

Comment: You do need to specify the type, either with an inline annotation or with a signature in a separate definition. By the way, there is a [planned GHC extension](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10803) that will provide syntax sugar for your second snippet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can shorten it slightly to

```
query_ "select * from books" >>= writeJSON . (\x -> x :: [Book])
```

Other than that, not yet, although there are plans to implement a GHC extension for a shortcut syntax

```
(:: [Book]) = (\x -> x :: [Book])
```

Looking at [@duplode's link](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10803)
it seems like the code for it started getting written 3 days ago, so should be in the next GHC release.

Answer (score 5):

If you turn on `PartialTypeSignatures`, you can write:

```
query_ "select * from books" >>= (writeJSON :: [Book] -> _)
```

One could also spell this as a constraint on `query_`; e.g. in your `do` version, it would be:

```
listBooks :: AppHandler ()
listBooks = do
  results <- query_ "select * from books" :: _ [Book]
  writeJSON results
```

In future versions of GHC, there will also be visible type application. Assuming that `writeJSON` or `query_` has a suitable type declaration, you would then be able to write one of these:

```
query_ @[Book] "select * from books" >>= writeJSON
query_ "select * from books" >>= writeJSON @[Book]
```

Finally, if you are averse to type annotations but okay with term annotations, you could write

```
query_ "select * from books" >>= asAppliedTo [Book{}] writeJSON
```

where `Book` is a hypothetical constructor for the `Book` type (the point being that `[Book{}]`, while a nonsense value, has a monomorphic type). I seem to recall that `asAppliedTo` is a standard thing, but a quick hoogle doesn't reveal it; in any case, it is implemented similar to this:

```
asAppliedTo :: arg -> (arg -> result) -> (arg -> result)
asAppliedTo _ = id
```

Comment: For a "standard thing" there is [`asTypeOf :: a -> a -> a; asTypeOf = const`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:asTypeOf).